# How to find the degree of a polynomial reading input of polynomial from a file?

Tags: c

The format of the polynomial is-

```
578.9x^45+564x^3+23x+1
```

I have tried declaring it as a string and then storing element next to '^' in a new string. Then I compared it and find the largest element in that string. But I am unable to figure out how to do the same thing when the degree is greater than 9. Also, I have to declare another an 1 d array of floating point value whose size will be the degree of the polynomial. So I must store the degree which is a string to int.

I'm having trouble converting 'q' to an int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
   char f[1000];
   FILE *input=fopen("input.txt","r");
   fgets(f,1000,input);
   printf("%s\n",f);
   char a[400],d[10],n;
   int i,j,k,m,l;
   m=strlen(f);
   //printf("%d\n",m);
   if(f[0]== '-')
   {
       for(k=0;k<10;k++)
        {
       for(i=0;i<m;i++)
       {
           if(f[i]=='x' && f[i+1]=='^')
           {
               d[k]=f[i+2];
               k=k+1;
               //break;
           }
       }
        }
   }
  l=strlen(d);
  char q;
  //printf("%d\n",l);
  for(i=1;i<l;i++)
  {
      q=d[0];
      if(d[0]<d[i])
      {
          d[0]=d[i];
      }
      q=d[0];
  }
  printf("%c\n",q);
 printf("%s\n",d);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your code here. We are not here to do your home work.

Comment: Why don't you copy as long as it is a digit?

Comment: Actually, I did that and I got the degree. But it's a char type and I don't know how to convert it to integer type?

Comment: Be careful here... `char` is a character type used to store a character like `'a'`, `'X'` or `'7'` ..  But your degree is a character string (could be one or more characters). You don't want to convert q as a number, (if degree is 71, you don't want 7 or 1, you want 71)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of char string you can input it using a numeric string. Find the ascii value of ^(say x) and keep storing the element next to it. In case of elements greater than 9, there are only two possibnilities , either there can be a '+' operator or '-' operator. Keep storing the value after x  in a temp variable until you reach the ascii code of '+' or '-'.

```
temp=0;
while(not reached '+' or '-')
{
    temp = arr[k] + temp*10;
     k++;
}
```

Now store temp in the list and now you can easily sort.

Answer (score 0):

To find the degree of a polynomial, all you have to do is find the largest exponent in the polynomial (where the base isn't 0).

This means we're only interested in this kind of strings: `[number]x^[number]`, where `[number]` is any decimal fraction, positive or negative. There are many ways to look for such strings, but I won't try to be smart of efficient, so I will choose the laziest one, which is  using `sscanf` at every string offset, which is, of course, horribly inefficient, but does the job. I won't do any error checks either.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INPUT_FILE_PATH "input.txt"

static char *readAllFile(const char *path, const char *mode, size_t *len) {
    char *s = NULL;
    FILE *f = fopen(path, mode);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t fsize = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);
    s = malloc(fsize);
    fread(s, 1, fsize, f);
    fclose(f);
    if (len != NULL) *len = fsize;
    return s;
}

int main(void) {
    size_t len;
    char *s = readAllFile(INPUT_FILE_PATH, "r", &len);
    float maxDegree = FLT_MIN;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        float base, degree;
        if (sscanf(s + i, "%fx^%f", &base, &degree) == 2) {
            if (base != 0 && degree > maxDegree) maxDegree = degree;
        }
    }
    printf("%f\n", maxDegree);
    free(s);
}
```

Some testing:

- `578.9x^45+564x^3+23x+1` => `45`
- `321.4x^2+0.0x^235-4+16x^3` => `3`
- `1.654x^-15+65x^-3-2x^2` => `2`